# Getting string array from String values folder?

Tags: android

In my Values folder for my project, I have a string array named currency_avatar. I want to be able to use this array of strings in my activity.

I know that "R.array.currency_array" this line of code is legal, however I do not know how to actually get this to refer to a local String array in my own activity.

So, how do I refer this currency_array located in my values folder of res to a local String array variable in my activity?

Sorry for such a simple question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String[] currencies = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currency_array)
```

Comment: I knew it was some type of syntax I was missing. Thanks so much. :)